# Counting the number of filled fields with javascript, ajax, or php on client side?

Tags: javascript, forms, count, field

I have 9 input's and 30 textarea's in one form. A few of the inputs are automatically filled. I need to count the ones that are filled.

Is there a javascript, ajax, or any other script language that can do this?  My form can be seen at:

http://www.41q.org/admin/data/register_form.php

(This webpage is included in another secured webpage via javascript)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = document.forms['form_register'].elements,
    not_filled = 0;
for( var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
   if( elements[i].value.length === 0 ) {
       // do something to the element?
       not_filled++;
   }
}
console.log(not_filled, " elements were no filled");
```

Note: i'm not sure if JS should be the only validation you run... server side validation is always recommended.

Comment: How do I get the number to show up in a field and can it be outside the form so it does not get counted?

Comment: where i have console.log you would just take that value and put it anywhere you would like... if this is beyond your javascript skills then a quick refresher of the basics might be a good idea.

Comment: but to be a nice guy.... look up `getElementById()` and `appendChild()`. also look up **replace element content without `innerHTML()`**